# Build gradle multi module project in parallel

Tags: gradle, parallel-processing, build.gradle

I have a project setup like this:

```
:root
  :common
  :module1
  :module2
  :module3
  :module4
  :app
```

The dependencies between the modules are like this:

```
:common --> "none"
:module* --> :common
:app --> "all other modules"
```

The root build gradle defines just a buildscript for certain plugins (like the kotlin gradle plugin). The actual application of the plugins happens in the module build.gradle files. Also no configuration injection takes place since all modules are responsible only for themselves.

I enabled org.gradle.parallel in my gradle.properties and run `./gradlew build`

The expected execution order would be the following (irrelevant tasks omitted):

```
:common:build
  :module1:build
  :module2:build
  :module3:build
  :module4:build
    :app:build
```

But unfortunately I got:

```
:common:build
  :module1:build
    :module2:build
      :module3:build
        :module4:build
          :app:build
```

Is there anything I can do to build all the modules in parallel since in the end there will be many more modules and the sequential execution will unnecessarily expand the needed build time even further.

Comment: `org.gradle.parallel` has been set for every project ?

Comment: yes it is set in the project wide gradle.properties

Comment: Do you see in the standard output the different task running in parallel though ? Maybe try to be sure the `--parallel` option in command line